# Set alarm according to timepicker in android

Tags: android, alarm, timepicker

I want a app that sets a alarm according to a time-picker and not a data-picker, i want the alarm to go off every day at the time the time-picker is set at.

I don't want to have a button which becomes a picker i want to use the time-picker icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a Button without Text, you can use

```
<ImageButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/button_icon"
... />
```

If you want to set up an Alarm create a new class, that shows TimePicker in FragmentDialog

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

      // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
      return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
              DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
   }

   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
      // Here you get the selected Time, do whatever you want
   }
}
```

And in the Activity, where is the Button:

```
<Button 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/pick_time" 
   android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog" />
```

Set OnclickListener, which starts FragmentDialog with TimePicker

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
   DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
   newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker

I dont really understand, what are you actually asking for. Clarify your question please.